# C++ use enumerated and , Change the value of the variable

Tags: c++

I have this question in my Home Work "use C++" :

Q: Complete the following program as required in comments, and then show the output.

```
 #include <iostream>

 using std::cout;

 using std::cin;

 using std::endl;

// Define an enumerated datatype Language

// Its legal values are german,english,spanish,and turkish 

 int main()

 {

 /* Define a varaible lang of type Language  */

 /* Set the varaible lang with the value german */

 /* Write a statement to print the value of the varaible lang */

 /* Change the value of the varible lang to turkish */



 return 0; 
} // end main
```

- I did writing code like these.

  ```
  #include <iostream>


   using std::cout;


  #include <iostream>
  using std::cout;

  using std::cin;

  using std::endl;

   // Define an enumerated datatype Language
   // Its legal values are german,english,spanish,and turkish 


   enum language { german, english, spanish, turkish };

   int main()
   {
   enum language { german, english, spanish, turkish };   
   /* Define a varaible lang of type Language  */
    language lang;
     /* Set the varaible lang with the value german */
     lang=german;
   /* Write a statement to print the value of the varaible lang */
     cout<<lang <<endl;
   /* Change the value of the varible lang to turkish */
     lang=turkish;
     cout<<lang<<endl;
   return 0;

   } // end main
  ```

I tried to answer,  but that what I can do :$

it's sure my answer false ,
 I really can't understand these part:

/* Change the value of the variable lang to turkish */ !!

I want know how to solve these, Can you help me , please ? :$

Thank you.

Comment: Well, that's all there is to it. You actually did it right. One thing though : you redeclared `enum language` in `main()`, that was not asked (it should be inherited from the global scope).

Comment: You've solved the problem correctly

Comment: Thanks then output should be 0 3 ?

Comment: @Sara_a yes that is correct since the number evaluates to the index of the enum - Enum by default start at 0 and yours ends at 3. So when you print the first option(german) it prints 0 and last option(turkish) it prints 3

Comment: Look at the result, your program display 0 3 so value of ```lang``` has successfully changed.

Comment: OoOh that's great thank you all I am happy , now I understand what the problem was. thank you all again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the comment of the assignment there is written

> Define an enumerated datatype **Language**

So you have to use name `Language` instead of `language`.

In your program you defined two enumerations with the same name, The last declaration within function main hides the declaration with the same name in the global namespace, It is obvious that there is no need to define two enumerations. One of them you may remove.

You could write for example

```
#include <iostream>

enum Language { german, english, spanish, turkish };

int main() 
{ 
    /* Define a varaible lang of type Language */ 
    Language lang; 

    /* Set the varaible lang with the value german */ 
    lang = german; 

    /* Write a statement to print the value of the varaible lang */ 
    std::cout << lang << std::endl;

    /* Change the value of the varible lang to turkish */ 
    lang = turkish; 
}
```

You may add an output statement after changing variable lang.

```
//...
    /* Change the value of the varible lang to turkish */ 
    lang = turkish; 

    std::cout << lang << std::endl;
}
```